# animated button on the left and right on xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, animation, button

in my interface there is a button named Forme1 and two arrows one on the left and on the right of the button 
I want when I click on the arrow on the right/left show me another button: button 2(Forme2)
with an animation

Comment: Could you explain further, and what have you tried

Comment: I want to place 4 button an a UIScrollView and if I click on a arrow button it display each time one of the 4 button